# JSDoc - How to document a limited number of values and their type for a parameter?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc3

I am using JSDoc to document a method; As you can see below I need to describe the parameter `to` where I need to document, that the value is of type `string` or `number` **only** and the accepted values are only these one:

```
TYPE:     VALUES ONLY ACCEPTED:
string - 'move:next'
string - 'move:prev'
number -  any number
```

How to pass this information to JSDoc?

---

```
        /**
         * Description here
         * @memberof app
         * @method _moveTo
         * @param {string|number} [to=move:next] [to=move:prev] - Some description.
         */

        _moveTo: function (to) {
            var isValid = true,
                goToIndex = this._focus,
                hasItem;
            if (to === 'move:next') {
                goToIndex++;
            } else if (to === 'move:prev') {
                goToIndex--;
            } else if (typeof to === 'number') {
                goToIndex = to;
            } else {
                isValid = false;
            }
            // more code...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delimit the acceptable strings by '|', like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param {'move:next'|'move:prev'|number} to - Some description.
 * ...
 */
```